# I want to redirect/rewrite my existing url

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

This url http://dreamsmember.com/xxxx/   have to be 
replaced with http://dreamsmember.com/web/default.aspx?v=xxxx

Here xxxx is dynamic, it can be something like xxxx=google, xxxx=microsoft

Comment: have you tried anything????

Comment: Replace with? How does that work? I mean you land on the page and then before posting it back you want to append the parameter to the URL?

Comment: I mean if someone put the value /xxxx then it will pass this value to default.aspx page as query string. My main objective is to get the value xxxx from default.aspx page. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example. based on the textbox input the querystring is given.

```
Response.Redirect("http://dreamsmember.com/web/default.aspx?v='" & txt.text & "' ")
```